# Como pesquisar uma palavra em um intervalo na frase

Tags: php

Preciso pesquisar uma palavra em um intervalo na frase. Exemplo a frase abaixo:

> O HTML foi criado em 1991, por Tim Berners-Lee, no CERN (European
>   Council for Nuclear Research) na suíça. Inicialmente o HTML foi
>   projetado para interligar instituições de pesquisa próximas, e
>   compartilhar documentos com facilidade. Em 1992, foi liberada a
>   biblioteca **ACPU** desenvolvimento WWW ( World Wide Web), uma rede de
>   alcance mundial, que junto com o HTML proporcionou o uso em escala
>   mundial da WEB.

Sempre neste texto vou separar em uma variável a palavra que estiver entre **biblioteca** e **desenvolvimento** que neste caso único e específico seria **ACPU**. Sempre terei o mesmo texto, porém a palavra no intervalo será diferente sempre.

Comment: o que você quer pesquisar exatamente?

Comment: Ficou confuso, porque "tudo" no source da img é != de "uma palavra" que também é != uma string do tipo: "power-pop.jpg"

Comment: Por acaso você quer pegar só o nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o `preg_match`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php 
    $str = 'O HTML foi criado em 1991, por Tim Berners-Lee, no CERN (European Council for Nuclear Research) na suíça. Inicialmente o HTML foi projetado para interligar instituições de pesquisa próximas, e compartilhar documentos com facilidade. Em 1992, foi liberada a biblioteca ACPU desenvolvimento WWW ( World Wide Web), uma rede de alcance mundial, que junto com o HTML proporcionou o uso em escala mundial da WEB.';
    $term1 = 'biblioteca';
    $term2 = 'desenvolvimento';

    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($term1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($term2).'/is', $str, $match);
    echo $match[1];
?>
```